# PHP Contact Form security

Tags: php, pear, contacts

I've tried searching for this but now I have more questions.

I've created a Php "contact us" form for my website. I understand that captcha is a must, what are my options for someone trying to hack? Just htmlentites or htmlspecialchars?

I saw someone mentioning pear mail, but I'm new to all of this and don't understand how to use pear mail (even after reading the instructions). If pear mail is the way to go can someone explain to me what I'm supposed to do to begin using it?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Try asking one question at a time. It is a quite complicated thing - to teach you how to program in just one answer.

Comment: Check this https://www.owasp.org

Comment: and this stackoverflow.com/questions/3273846/beginning-web-security

Comment: @zerkms too late for this post, but I'll keep that in mind for the next post.

Answer (score 1):

Captcha is not a must, only if you let your users control where the e-mails are send to (as if then hackers could spam other people with your form) - captcha is not very user friendly (depending the securitylevel). You could set a cookie to prevent double posts. If you get a lot of spams then, you could add a captcha or log IP's and require a captcha after one or two form submits. For html/email security is htmlspecialchars the way to go; i always use strip_tags, as it strips down all tags and only allows tekst.

Edit: in addition, of course, the more secure the better - but in this case for a 'contact us' form, in the case of some abuse attacks, the only one is getting spam is your company. The abuser will stop, as is has no use (unless he likes it to be mean to you). You could ban the IP.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that! 

Now I understand that I was trying to do more than what I need to do. I will be using the strip_tags!

Thanks for taking the time to explain it to a noob, and not being rude!

Comment: You could (must) use both then! As using strip_tags won't convert the characters to html (if your output is a html email). So it will be htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['yourinput'])) - as said htmlspecialchars will be good too. You can get an email with some strange contents, but it won't harm - in fact it's maybe better as you can then ban that visitor :)